# How do I check if a link exists in a page?

Tags: 7, testing

There is a form having a link clicking on which field set will be collapsed to show fields under it. HTML is shown as below.

```
<span class="fieldset-legend">
  <a href="#" class="fieldset-title">
    <span class="fieldset-legend-prefix element-invisible">Hide</span>
    Attach
  </a>
<span class="summary"></span></span>
```

How would I go about checking if this link exists (to click on it), and the fields under it are shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I realized (even without clicking on the link) that fields can be asserted by `DrupalWebTestCase::assertFieldByName()`.